# calling git in python

Tags: python, git

I have set up several git repositories that are linked with tfs. I would like to have a python script to push the code into tfs.I can't download any thrid part libraires like GitPython. should I use the sys module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/)

```
from fabric.api import local # or run for remote systems

with cd('mydirectory'):
    local('git status')
```